# Python regex to replace line in file

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a quick and dirty build script that needs to update a couple of lines in a small xml config file. Since the file is so small, I'm using an admittedly inefficient process to update the file in place just to keep things simple:

```
def update_xml(property, value):
  for line in fileinput.input(os.path.join(app_dir, 'my.xml'), inplace=True):
    if property is 'version':
      line = re.sub(r'(<version>).*?(</version>)', '\1%s\2' % value, line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    elif property is 'brand':
      line = re.sub(r'(<property name="brand" type="string">).*?(</property>)', '\1%s\2' % value, line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    elif property is 'env':
      line = re.sub(r'(<property name="env" type="string">).*?(</property>)', '\1%s\2' % value, line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    print line
```

I have 2 problems:

- The back references aren't capturing what I expect. Instead of getting `<version>a.b.c</version>`, for example, I get the version value surrounded by control characters. I've tried doubling up the backslash, removing the formatted print and a couple of other things, but can't get it quite right.
- When I write the line back to the file (`print line`), I get several extra line breaks.

What am I borking up here?

Comment: Try to replace "\1%s\2" by "\g<1>%s\g<2>" , it might be the problem..

Comment: Okay. I had just read about that syntax, but didn't really understand the variance. Nonetheless, that did the trick. Any idea about the extra linebreaks? If you'll move your comment to an answer, I'll mark it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `"\1%s\2" by "\g<1>%s\g<2>"` , it might be the problem..

About the newlines , the print might be adding a second new line on top of the existing one .

you can try: `print line,` with a comma to suppress the new line char

Comment: Thanks for your help, @andsoa. For the new lines, I just replace every instance of `line` within the loop with `line.strip()` and it seems to do the trick for whatever reason. The script is dirty enough that I'm not going to spend any more time with it. :-)

Comment: thanks :) i didn't know about the fileinput module. So i also learned something cool here ! btw: fileinput module says this --Lines are returned with any newlines intact, which means that the last line in a file may not have one.--

Answer (score 0):

Use a raw string to avoid `\1` and `\2` becoming control chars: `r'\1%s\2'`

Comment: FWIW, I did try this at the time, but didn't have any luck with it. I'm a Python n00b, though, so I may have just borked it up somehow.